# Getting Error in the code ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected

Tags: solidity, remix

```
 pragma solidity >= 0.8.2 <0.9.0;

contract Types { 
// Declaring a dynamic array
uint[] data; 
uint8 j = 0;
 function loop() public returns(uint[] memory){
while(j < 5) {
j++;
data.push(j);
}
return data;
}
 }

 On Remix IDE getting the error. ParserError: Function, variable, 
 struct or modifier declaration expected.
 --> contracts/Types.sol:5:16:
    |
  5 | contract Types { 
    |                ^
```

Comment: I checked the code in Remix and it does compile and deploy successfully. Could use some linting, but it does work.

Comment: I had the same positive result, can't find any errors...

Comment: the code compiles well on remix

Answer (score 0):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0




pragma solidity >=0.8.2 <0.9.0;

contract Types { 
   
    uint[] data; 
    uint8 j = 0;

    function loop() public returns (uint[] memory) {
        while (j < 5) {
            j++;
            data.push(j);
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

as far as i can see, you just forget the license identifier to the top